# How to change the width of a code block in an asciidoc file?

Tags: documentation-generation, asciidoc

Is there any way to modify the width of a source code block in an asciidoc file instead of having to scroll horizontally to show its content?

The Asciidoc documentation does not say if changing the width of a block in general is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Asciidoc markup provides both the content and suggestions for how that content should be rendered. But, it doesn't get into the weeds for presentation. That's what the "theme" is for.

Can you demonstrate the problem? The default theme for Asciidoctor does wrap wide code blocks, including lines with no whitespace. For example, this document:

```
= Document

Lorem ipsum...

[source, js]
----
// This is a really long line that we'd like to wrap and avoid having a horizontal scroll bar appear, but that's just awkward for everyone involved.
// ========================================================================================================================================================================================
----
```

Renders as:

[image: Code block with text wrapping]

If you have source block content that isn't wrapping as you'd like, you'll need to first find out why the wrapping does not happen, and how you might change the CSS styles to fix the problem.

Then, you should be able to create some "docinfo" files to embed your CSS fix. See [Docinfo Files](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/docinfo/) for details.